# Instagram Subscription

Tags: instagram, sandbox, subscription

I have followed Instagram documentation (https://www.instagram.com/developer/subscriptions/) on how to create a user subscription.

This is the response that I get after creating the subscription:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200
    },
    "data": {
        "object": "user",
        "object_id": null,
        "aspect": "media",
        "subscription_id": 0,
        "callback_url": "http://CALLBACK_URL",
        "type": "subscription",
        "id": 0
    }
}
```

Some of the users that have authenticated with my app have posted some media and yet I'm not seeing anything from my end, which makes me think that there might be an error with the subscription.

subscription_id or id 0 does not look correct to me. My app is still in Sandbox mode, is this the problem?

Also, I have tried creating another subscription with object=tag and object_id=blah but it returns the same response as above.

Any advice would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you end up resolving this issue? Have the same issue here.

Comment: Can I know what is the end use case of this API from a user perspective?

Answer (score 1):

The `subscription_id=0` looks weird but it's **normal** in sandbox. Perhaps you can make sure your callback `url` is actually receiving the `post` from Instagram properly (save it to a log to test).